# Is there a way to generate a function where the object name changes with the input of the function?

Tags: r

Something as such:

```
gen_sigma <- function(i) {
  sigma_`i` <- matrix(c(1, i, i, 1), nrow = 2, byrow = TRUE)
}
```

Comment: The recommended way would be to do the assignment outside of the function.  Also, you would usually do this by assigning into a list. Almost certainly cleaner to do it that way, and you would need a *very* good reason and exceptional circumstances to do what you propose instead.  I.e. `sigma[[i]] <- gen_sigma(i)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 'right' thing to do is to use a list as follows, rather than polluting your environment with lots of variable names. This is an example:

```
n = 10

res_list = vector(length = n, mode = 'list')

for (i in 1:n) {
    res_list[[i]] = matrix(c(1, i, i, 1), nrow = 2, byrow = TRUE)
}
```

or using `lapply`

```
n = 10
res_list = lapply(1:n, function(x) matrix(c(1, x, x, 1), nrow = 2, byrow = TRUE))
```

One other option is to use `assign` and `get`, although I would hope there is a cleaner solution than this, as using these functions is often a bit of a code-smell. I think putting it into a list would likely be the best solution.

```
gen_sigma <- function(i) {
    output_name = paste0("sigma_", i)
    assign(output_name, matrix(c(1, i, i, 1), nrow = 2, byrow = TRUE), envir=parent.frame())
    get(output_name)
}
```

```
gen_sigma(5)
> sigma_5
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1    5
[2,]    5    1
```